# NPM test issue in VSTS

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have one private build agent in VSTS which I configured back in March this year, now I wanted to deploy a second one, but I'm having issue with NPM test task on the new build agent. It's using the same Agents package published by Microsoft, so I don't believe the issue should be there. I have install the same version of Node.js (6.10.1) and the same NPM version (5.10.10) on both agents, but the new one has issue where the task **npm test** executes in the build definition, but does not produce any result and neither is anything shown in the VSTS log files/console, it just hangs until timeout period is reached (80 minutes), or until I cancel it manually. When I run it locally on the agent it works perfectly fine, I also tried running it in the pipeline via the CMD task, not the NPM and it also works, so I know there is no issue with the server/connectivity/etc.

If someone experienced a similar issue, I would really welcome some insights into this problem, because as I've mentioned, same pipeline works on the first agent, so the configuration of the tasks, pipeline, code/folder structure cannot be the issue here.

Log file from the VSTS agent follows, manual cancel at the end after 7 minutes,
 because normally it takes around 20 seconds (XXXXX is the path to project):

```
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO StepsRunner] Processing step: DisplayName='Execute React Unit Tests', ContinueOnError=False, Enabled=True
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO ExpressionManager] Evaluating: succeeded()
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO ExpressionManager] Expanded: True
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO ExpressionManager] Result: True
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO StepsRunner] Starting the step.
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO TaskManager] Loading task definition 'C:\VSTSAgent\_work\_tasks\Npm_fe47e961-9fa8-4106-8639-368c022d43ad\1.0.8\task.json'.
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO ExtensionManager] Getting extensions for interface: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.IJobExtension'
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO BuildJobExtension] Build JobExtension resolving path use source provide: XXXXX
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO BuildJobExtension] The Default Path Root of Build JobExtension is build.sourcesDirectory: C:\VSTSAgent\_work\7\s
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO BuildJobExtension] After prefix Default Path Root provide by JobExtension: C:\VSTSAgent\_work\7\s\XXXXX
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO BuildJobExtension] Return absolute path after prefix DefaultPathRoot: C:\VSTSAgent\_work\7\s\XXXXX
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO TaskRunner] Build JobExtension resolved a rooted path:: C:\VSTSAgent\_work\7\s\XXXXX
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO ExtensionManager] Getting extensions for interface: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.IJobExtension'
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO BuildJobExtension] Build JobExtension resolving path use source provide: 
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO BuildJobExtension] The Default Path Root of Build JobExtension is build.sourcesDirectory: C:\VSTSAgent\_work\7\s
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO BuildJobExtension] After prefix Default Path Root provide by JobExtension: C:\VSTSAgent\_work\7\s
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO BuildJobExtension] Return absolute path after prefix DefaultPathRoot: C:\VSTSAgent\_work\7\s
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO TaskRunner] Build JobExtension resolved a rooted path:: C:\VSTSAgent\_work\7\s
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO NodeHandler] Inspect node_modules folder, make sure vsts-task-lib doesn't overwrite String.startsWith/endsWith.
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO NodeHandler] This task has already been scanned and corrected, no more operation needed.
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Bin': 'C:\VSTSAgent\bin'
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Root': 'C:\VSTSAgent'
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Externals': 'C:\VSTSAgent\externals'
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO ProcessInvoker] Starting process:
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO ProcessInvoker]   File name: 'C:\VSTSAgent\externals\node\bin\node.exe'
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO ProcessInvoker]   Arguments: '"C:\VSTSAgent\_work\_tasks\Npm_fe47e961-9fa8-4106-8639-368c022d43ad\1.0.8\npm.js"'
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO ProcessInvoker]   Working directory: 'C:\VSTSAgent\_work\7\s'
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO ProcessInvoker]   Require exit code zero: 'True'
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO ProcessInvoker]   Encoding web name: utf-8 ; code page: '65001'
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO ProcessInvoker]   Force kill process on cancellation: 'False'
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO ProcessInvoker] Process started with process id 4124, waiting for process exit.
[2017-11-27 14:24:29Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1.
[2017-11-27 14:24:30Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to upload 1 log files or attachments, success rate: 1/1.
[2017-11-27 14:24:32Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1.
[2017-11-27 14:24:33Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1.
[2017-11-27 14:24:34Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1.
[2017-11-27 14:24:34Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1.
[2017-11-27 14:31:34Z INFO Worker] Cancellation/Shutdown message received.
```

Comment: What's the differences of the two private agent capabilities (you can compare in `https://account.visualstudio.com/_admin/_AgentPool` page -> selecting a agent pool and agent -> Capabilities Tab)?

Comment: Good point, I checked the capabilities, and the only relevant diference was that on the old agent, I had JDK 8.121, and on the new one I had 8.151. However after another run, it still doesn't work.